# How can an open set be equal to a union of half-open sets?

Tags: measure-theory

In discussing $\sigma$-algebras I have seen the following used in proofs:

$$(0,1)=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \left[ \frac{1}{n} , 1 \right)$$

In other words the open set is equal to a denumerable union of half-open/half-closed sets. The missing link is supposed to be the fact that $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable unions. But what is the link? How can the equal sign be used since $\frac{1}{n}$ will always be greater than $0$?

Comment: It's true that every element of $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[\frac1n,1)$ is greater than $0.$ Why is that a problem? It's also true that every element of $(0,1)$ is greater than $0.$. If you think the two sets are not equal, why don't you give us a number which you think belongs to one but not the other?

Comment: Note your problem is similar to how some people have trouble with the equals sign in $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$: you're thinking "some arbitrarily large but finite $n$" rather than "the nested union over all $n$".

Comment: That equation is equivalent to:$$\forall x,(0<x<1)\iff(\exists n,\frac1n\le x<1)$$

Comment: By the way, I'm assuming $[1,1)$ is defined to be $\{x:1\le x<1\}=\{\}$.

Comment: Somebody needs an epsilon - also upvoters would you really say this question is well researched?

Answer (score 11):

The fact that $\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},1) = (0,1)$ doesn't have anything to do with $\sigma$-algebras.

The equality follows from the fact that if $0<x<1$ then there is some $n$ so that $0<\frac{1}{n}<x<1$, which gives that $(0,1)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},1)$. And, further that $[\frac{1}{n},1)\subseteq (0,1)$ for each $n$, and so $\bigcup_{n=2}^\infty [\frac{1}{n},1) \subseteq (0,1)$.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, neither set is a closed set, so the question in your title is not the same as the question in the body.

To understand how $(0,1) = \cup_n [\frac 1n, 1)$, you might show that these two sets contain eachother. It is clear that the right is in the left. Let us show that the left is in the right.

Choose some number $\delta \in (0,1)$. Then since there is an $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \delta$, we see that $\delta \in$ that $[\frac 1n, 1)$. This is true for every number on the left, and so the left set is contained in the right. Thus they are equal.

To answer the question in your title, both the empty set and the entire set are both open and closed. And depending on your topology, many other sets as well.

Comment: Thanks mixedMath and James. It suddenly became clear....

Answer (score 0):

Since $0$ is not in $(0,1)$. Every number $r$ in $(0,1)$ is in some $[\frac{1}{n}, 1)$.

Comment: I've given you an upvote (this was on -1) and while the logic is totally correct, this really ought to be a comment unless fleshed out a bit.... maybe - clearly the OP doesn't get this so....

Answer (score 0):

The point is that open sets do not contain their boundary points. For any $x \in (0,1)$, there is strictly positive distance of $x$ from $0$. For some large $n$, we will have $1/n$ is smaller than this distance, so $x \in [1/n,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $A:=\bigcup_nA_n$ is the set of all numbers that are in at least one of the $A_n$. That is, if $x\in A_5$, then $x\in A$. If $x\in A_{1000}$, then $x\in A$. But if $x\not\in A_n$ for *any* $n$, then $x\not\in A$.

That means that $B:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,1\right)$ is the set of all numbers that are in some set of the form $\left[\frac1n,1\right)$. So, for example, we know that $0.1\in B$, because $0.1\in\left[\frac1{10},1\right)$. But $0\not\in B$, because $0\not\in\left[\frac1n,1\right)$ for *any* $n$. Similarly, $1\not\in B$. As it turns out, any number in $(0,1)$ (and only those numbers) is in a set of that form; thus $(0,1)=B$.

In fact, the statement $(0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac1n,1\right)$ is equivalent to:
$$\forall x,(0<x<1)\iff(\exists n,\frac1n\le x<1)$$
(but with fewer symbols).